# Pyramid on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyramid, linode

What is the experience like with Pyramid on Heroku? The idea of not having to worry about sys admin is very alluring but I'd like to know if there are any caveats before I switch from Linode.

Answer (score 2):

The usual with heroku: you don't have a persistent file system, so file upload is not as straightforward as usual. Other than that, it works quite nicely.

There's even recipe in the cookbook that deals with the specifics: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/heroku.html.